# Can I override svn:ignore for individual directories?

Tags: svn, svnignore

The default global ignore for Subversion does a good job of keeping build artifacts out of version control.  What if I need to distribute a directory of compiled code for my stuff to build?

I don't want to pick up my *output* (in, say, `/target`), and I want to continue ignoring *all* compiled code for most of my other projects, but just *one* directory (say, `/input`) needs to always track files with a `.a` extension.

Is there a property I can set on the `/input` directory that will make `svn add` pick up new `.a` files in there, without altering the global-ignores property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `svn:ignore` setting is a per-directory property. It applies to a given directory, and *adds to* rather than *overrides* the `global-ignores` setting. See [Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) in the SVN book.

I would say you have two viable options:

1. Don't include `*.a` in the `global-ignores` setting, but rather only set it in the `svn:ignore` property on directories where such files tend to appear, such as `/target`.
2. Keep `*.a` in the `global-ignores` setting, and manually call `svn add` on each of the `.a` files you wish to track. Once they are tracked by SVN, the ignore setting will no longer apply to them.

Comment: Right, but what's the syntax for saying *don't* ignore (this pattern)?  I mean, if it's already ignored, how do I "un-ignore" it?

Comment: remove it from the svn:ignore property. svn propedit svn:ignore

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#id3022585 tells "The patterns are strictly for that directory—they do not carry recursively into subdirectories."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the situation properly at first. I amended my answer. I don't think the ideal solution exists, but you can get pretty comfortable with either of the above suggestions.

Comment: I tried to make it clear in the original question... I knew about both of those options, and they both have enough drawbacks that I wanted to avoid them if at all possible.  If these are the only options, I just wanted to see it said in black-and-white.

Comment: It may be that there is a way of doing it that I am not aware of, but it doesn't seem that way from the docs. Sorry.

Comment: Accepting this because the short version is "no, you can't do what you want", and this is what you're stuck with :-/

Answer (score 0):

Just encounter this issue and solved in `SmartSVN` Client (but the solution should be applicable to other SVN clients).
You should be able to manually include an ignored file/directory without changing any `svn:ignore` settings.

The problem you might have is that the files may not be visible so you will have to show them first.

Solution:

- Show ignored files
- Right click the ignore file/directory and click "Add"